# Intellij remote host sometimes takes over 1 minute to upload changes

Tags: php, database, intellij-idea

I have configured intellij ultimate 15.0 to work with php, and I use it to FTP into my server. It works, but ever 4-5 times I upload the file, it takes over a minute. Normally I can upload the file changes in 5 seconds. This is a problem because it completely breaks my workflow. Does anyone know why this is happening? The reason I choose intellij over phpstorm is because I like the look and feel of it more. Thanks.

Installed phpstorm instead. Having the same problems :|

Comment: You upload one file or all changed files or all files?

Comment: Any log from ftp connection?

Comment: @Naumov Just one file at a time that I edit. Even if the edit is only 1 character it will sometimes take forever.

Comment: @JrBenito No there is not a log.

Comment: try use sftp or ssh for uploading.